# make * in Spacemacs work like it does in vim

Tags: spacemacs, evil, search, vim-emulation

In Spacemacs, is there an easy way to make <kbd>*</kbd> (which calls the function `spacemacs/enter-ahs-forward`) work like it does in Vim?

That is, I want <kbd>*</kbd> to perform forward searching like in Vim, without opening up the "Symbol Highlight Transient State".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching I have figured this out.

Evil actually already has the search-forward functionality just like vim.  Here is where the mapping to <kbd>*</kbd> is defined:

https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/427cf5faa57e8794ac93f594dc3d1972e687a25a/evil-maps.el#L232

However, it appears that spacemacs overrides this mapping:

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/b252d252b0e93249b51400f60a0c69a59aa140a4/layers/%2Bspacemacs/spacemacs-editing-visual/packages.el#L173-L177

Spacemacs is using [`use-package` to load the `auto-highlight-symbol` package](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/b252d252b0e93249b51400f60a0c69a59aa140a4/layers/%2Bspacemacs/spacemacs-editing-visual/packages.el#L38-L40), and in the `:config` section it is overwriting the mapping for <kbd>*</kbd>.

So in order to overwrite this mapping, it is neccesary to call `define-key` after `auto-highlight-symbol` has already been loaded.  The following code can be put in your `.spacemacs` file:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (with-eval-after-load 'auto-highlight-symbol
    (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "*") 'evil-search-word-forward)))
```

The following can be used if you want to overwrite both forward search and backward search:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (with-eval-after-load 'auto-highlight-symbol
    (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "*") 'evil-search-word-forward)
    (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "#") 'evil-search-word-backward)))
```

Comment: That worked like a charm for me, with the only nagging that the searched term _does not_ populate the search history. Therefore, when you do `/a`, position yourself over another word, say "bbb" and hit `*`, the next time you hit `n` you'll search for "a". I'll probably turn this into a question.

Answer (score 2):

Evil-visualstar is a package that provides the feature, but I am not sure of the compatibility with spacemacs.