# How can I make terms searched with `*` or `#` populate the search history?

Tags: spacemacs, evil

In my attempt to have `*` and `#` work in Spacemacs as they do in Vim, I've followed the solution posted [at this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36590/20349).

Those keys now work, but there's one hurdle more to overcome: the searched term does not populate the search history.

As an example, suppose you:

- do `/aaa`
- position yourself over another word, say "bbb" and hit `*`
- hit `n`

Spacemacs will search for "aaa" rather than "bbb".
Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `evil-symbol-word-search` to accomplish what you want by adding the following to you init.el after loading `evil`

```
(setq-default evil-symbol-word-search t)
```

Comment: I added that line under `dotspacemacs/user-init ()` to no avail. Should it go somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not familiar with spacemacs, though I would also try customizing that variable through `M-x customize`

Comment: I tried that, too, but it looks as if the variable does not have any effect (though being set to `t`)

Comment: What are <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd> mapped to? It says in the answer  that you linked that this mapping is overriden in spacemacs: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/c7a103a772d808101d7635ec10f292ab9202d9ee/layers/%2Bspacemacs/spacemacs-editing-visual/packages.el#L173-L177

Comment: They are bound to `evil-search-word-forward` and `backward`:
`(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
 (with-eval-after-load 'auto-highlight-symbol
 (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "*") 'evil-search-word-forward)
 (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "#") 'evil-search-word-backward)))`